# Error playing audio file from sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard, soundpool

guys i am using soundpool to play audio file from sdcard below is my code:

```
sound1 = mSoundPool.load(source_path, 5);

                hand1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (sound1 != 0) {
                            loaded = true;
                            mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    mSoundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 1, time - 1, 1);
                                    System.out.println("playing=== a");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }, 21000);
```

problem is its not playing the audio file.here time is value from edit text
i am working on android 2.2 please help